# How to get alternating page headers in Scrivener?

Tags: formatting, scrivener

Can anyone please help me with a small issue that I am facing right now with the headers in my Scrivener project. I am trying to add alternate headers to my project - Every even page to have the name of the book and every odd page to have the name of the author.

I have tried adding headers when compiling the book but it just adds one header to both odd and even the pages.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand that Scrivener is a *writing software*, not a publishing software. Formatting for print (or other publication) is not what Scrivener was made for. Usually you would import your compiled manuscript into something like Adobe InDesign and work on the layout of your book there.

That said, of course you can create different headers for even and odd pages in Scrivener. How it is done is explained in [this answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/14680/32754).